# Как убрать копирайт в WordPress с помощью функции?

Tags: wordpress

У меня на [сайте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) стоит платная премиум тема. Сайт сделан на Wordpress. Я создал дочернюю тему, чтобы при обновлении главной темы не слетали мои надстройки. Мне нужно удалить часть копирайта (а именно вот эту часть - ***$kriesi_at_backlink;***), но сделать это с помощью функции php в дочерней теме. Копирайт выводится вот так:

```
<?php echo $copyright . $kriesi_at_backlink; ?>
```

Как мне это реализовать? Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать...

Comment: Я надеюсь, я вас правильно понял. Вы хотите чтобы $kriesi_at_backlink; в копирайте не было?

Comment: @dbaishev Да, Вы правильно меня поняли. Но мне нужно не просто удалить эту переменную из файла footer.php, а в дочерней теме написать функцию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может с помощью хука переопределить переменную?
Допустим,

`add_action( 'get_footer', 'remove_copyright' );
function remove_copyright () {
global $kriesi_at_backlink;
$kriesi_at_backlink = "";
}`

Как-то так

Comment: @MrGaliev не работает код, но уже очень близко))